# Adding deploy:update_code to deployment script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm using **Capistrano 3**, and in its' wiki says there is a recipe `deploy:update_code`, which updates code. However when I'm trying to use it, there is an error:

> Don't know how to build task 'deploy:update_code'

Here is my **Capfile**:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano3/unicorn'
require 'capistrano/bower'
require 'capistrano/sidekiq'
require 'capistrano/newrelic'
require 'capistrano/thin'
```

Which receipe am i missing to use this task?

Answer (score 2):

`deploy:update_code` it's internal capistrano hook not a rake task, you can see it in the picture of the default strategy:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to call this hook in some custom rake task?

Comment: i assume you can't just run this hook, b'cause it's related on other hooks in strateges.
you can add `before` of `after` and pass own task. [Configuration Tasks Task](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Configuration-Tasks-Task)